# tell gradle to install aar and pom file of different built types into .m2 directory with different folders for each build type

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am new to the android world. Currently I have `release` and `debug` build type for my android project. I created a boolean variable `pushToArtifactory` to tell `uploadArchives` to upload my aar and pom files to artifactory or install them into my `.m2 repository`.

However, when I set `publishNonDefault` to `false` and use command `gradlew clean assemble uploadArchives`. aar. and pom files of both release and snapshot are in one folder.

Please let me know if there is a way to specify the archives for each build type to be installed into its own folder separately.

Thanks

Comment: Have you found an answer?